# pandas diff with date columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
d={'business':['FX','FX','IR','IR'],\
   'name':['ed','ed','a','b'],\
   'date':(['01/01/2018','05/02/2018','01/01/2018','05/01/2018']),\
   'amt':[1,2,3,4]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

I am trying to get a new column that shows the difference between the two dates using the diff() function. My final output that I need is:

```
df['date diff']=[0,4,0,0]
```

Note: the diff() function would result in a Nan for the 0's above which is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['date diff'] = df.groupby(['business','name'])['amt'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
  business name       date  amt  date diff
0       FX   ed 2018-01-01    1          0
1       FX   ed 2018-02-05    5          4
2       IR    a 2018-01-01  101          0
3       IR    b 2018-01-05  105          0
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.sort_values(['business','date'])
df['date diff'] = df.groupby(['business'])['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
  business name       date  amt  date diff
0       FX   ed 2018-01-01    1          0
1       FX   ed 2018-02-05    5         35
2       IR    a 2018-01-01  101          0
3       IR    b 2018-01-05  105          4
```

Comment: I need the difference between dates and not amt. I will edit the data to make it clear